# Probability of winning coin toss game

Tags: probability

A has 6 dollars and B has 4 dollars. They bet one dollar each time by flipping an unbiased coin until one of them runs out of money. What is the probability of A winning all the money.

Below I take  $P_{Ax}$ = Probability of A winning given he has x$.

I used $P_{A6} = P_{A8} * 0.5 + P_{A4} * 0.5$ where:

$P_{A8} = 1 * 0.5 + P_{A6} * 0.5$ and $P_{A4} = P_{B}$ implies $P_{A4} + P_{A6} = 1$ from which I get $P_{A6} = 3/5$. Does this answer make sense?
Thank You

Comment: Hint: Use the Partition theorem

Comment: $P_{10}=1, P_0=0, P_{i}=\frac 1 2 P_{i-1}+\frac 1 2 P_{i+1}$, hence $P_i=\frac i {10}$

Comment: @A.S. Thanks. However, shouldnt it be $P_{i} = 0.5P_{i-2} + 0.5P_{i+2}$? I guess this isn't too important. But from here how did you get $P_{i} = i/10$? I can see how you can calculate it by plugging in the boundary conditions, but is there some algebraic way that I am missing?

Comment: If you have $i$ dollars, you either lose one or gain one - not two. The recurrence for $P_i$ shows that $P_i$ must be linear (rewrite the terms to see that $P_i-P_{i-1}$ is constant) and boundary conditions determine the two free coefficients.